# using Blanket.js for a compoundjs app to generate coverage report

Tags: node.js, code-coverage, mocha.js, compoundjs

I have compoundjs application in which I have used the scaffold generator to generate controller and its test cases. The test cases are running correctly. But I need to generate the code coverage report for the same. I am trying to use ***blanket.js*** for the same.

I have configured *blanket.js* like this in *package.json* in scripts :

```
"blanket": { "pattern": "app" }
```

***app*** is the folder which contains all my controllers, models etc. And then I am running test cases having reporter as :

> mocha test/init.js test/controllers/sample_controller.test.js --require blanket -R html-cov > coverage.html

This is actually properly generating coverage report for it. But the problem I am facing is it is only showing the  code coverage for certain files like it is showing code coverage for `model/sample` but not for `controllers/sample_controller.js`.

Please help me out ASAP as I am actually stuck with it.
Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Try using `_mocha` instead of `mocha` to avoid mocha forking and not covering all of your code in the same process.

Option 2: I highly recommend istanbul as a coverage tool. Try:

```
npm -g install istanbul
istanbul cover _mocha -- test/init.js test/controllers/sample_controller.test.js --require blanket -R spec
open coverage/lcov-report/index.html
```

More info here: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/44

Answer (score 0):

These are eval controllers, right?  I'm investigate coverage for eval controllers in the next release of Blanket (v1.1.3).  In the meantime Istanbul is an option, as is grunt-blanket.